# If else does not works properly

Tags: javascript

I have a Function (with help of other user of stackoverflow), but only the first if statement works, the second not. I want to take advantage of this code to get both: http and https followed or not by www

```
function formatURL() {
  var url = document.getElementsByName("URL")[0];
  var formattedURL = document.getElementsByName("formattedURL")[0];
  url = url.value;
  if (url.substr(0, 0) === "") // with our without www
  {
    formattedURL.value = "https://" + url;
    return;
  } else
  {
    formattedURL.value = "http://" + url;
    return;
  }
}
formattedURL.value = url;
}
```

Comment: What do you think `url.substr(0, 0)` does?

Comment: `anyString.substr(0, 0)` will always be `=== ''`. Your first `if` will always match.

Comment: `if` `else` always work... their conditionals are the ones which fail (we think they evaluates to something, but they evaluate to something else)

Comment: I have changed it was  if (url.substr(0, 3) === "www"), however some urls does not have www after http and I don´t know as fix it.

Answer (score 2):

You're running into this issue because `url.substr(0,0)` will always be an empty string `""` for any string value of `url` (your `if` statement is always `true`).

Not sure what exactly you're trying to compare `url.substr` against because we don't have all the possible inputs you give to your `<URL/>` elements. Otherwise, I could have an actual **fix** for you.